# Possible to protect a Firebase app behind GCP's Identity Aware Proxy?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

My firebase app has a prod and a test environment. I would like to lock down the test environment completely to folks outside of my GSuite domain, so unauthorized folks can't see the app at all.

In appengine land, this is really straightforward using Cloud IAP (Identity-Aware Proxy). Is there an equivalent in the firebase world?

Note: this would layer on top of firebase auth. I don't want randoms to be able to even see the page, nor do I want to mess with the firebase auth config (which has its own rules, multiple service providers etc that I don't want to mess with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change your firebase auth configuration, there is no solution.

IAP is, today, only available for AppEngine and Compute Engine. Google work hard to integrate more service in it (Function, Cloud Run). But I never heard that firebase will be integrated.